# Problems with NSTokenField (again) - using objectvalue

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In my Swift Application for Mac OS X, I'm using a [NSTokenField](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTokenField_Class/). I'm using, among others, the delegate methods `tokenField(tokenField: NSTokenField, representedObjectForEditingString editingString: String) -> AnyObject` and `tokenField(tokenField: NSTokenField, displayStringForRepresentedObject representedObject: AnyObject) -> String?` to work with represented objects. My represented objects are instances of a custom class.

From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TokenField_Guide/GetSetTokenFields/GetSetTokenFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006555-CH9-SW2), I know that `objectValue` can be used to access the represented objects of a `NSTokenView` as a `NSArray`:

> To retrieve the objects represented by the tokens in a token field, send the token field an `objectValue` message. Although this method is declared by `NSControl`, `NSTokenField` implements it to return an array of represented objects. If the token field simply contains a series of strings, `objectValue` returns an array of strings. To set the represented objects of a token field, use the `setObjectValue`: method, passing in an array of represented objects. If these objects aren’t strings, `NSTokenField` then queries its delegate for the display strings to use for each token.

However, this doesn't seem to work for me. `let tokenArray = self.tokenField.objectValue! as! NSArray` does return a NSArray, but it is empty, even though the delegate method required to return a represented object has been called the appropriate amount of times before.

`NSTokenField` doesn't seem like a particularly strong tool to work with tokenization, but, lacking an alternative, I hope that you guys can help me making my implementation work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a quick demo app - implementing just ``tokenField:displayStringForRepresentedObject:`` - the token field's ``objectValue`` property behaved as described by the documentation. This makes me think the behavior you're getting is due to an issue elsewhere in your code. Can you post your implementation of the delegate methods along with a bit of info about your custom class?

Comment: What is `NSTokenView`?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
let tokenStrings = tokenField.objectValue as! [String]
```

where tokenField is the NSTokenField that you want to extract the strings from.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar. I was returning represented objects from `tokenField(_:shouldAdd:at:)`, and yet calling `myField.objectValue` returned a string with the same number of this character as there were tokens: `\U0000fffc`.

It turned out that I was using a `Formatter` on the token field which was creating an `NSTextAttachment` for each token. That's why each token was being represented as that enigmatic unicode string. When I removed the `Formatter` from the token field, `objectValue` started returning the represented objects as expected.